# Underscore in OGNL expression not working

Tags: struts2, ognl

I am surprised that underscore ("_") is not working in OGNL.
In below sample all properties are processed on OGNL/ValueStack, except property name appfull_name due to underscore.

### Code sample below

**POJO SampleSdmAppsTabObj.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="SDM_APPS")
@IdClass(SdmAppsPkeyObj.class)
public class SdmAppsTabObj implements Serializable 
{
  //@Id
   String                                orgid;
  //@Id
   String                                asnid;
   String                                appfull_name;
   String                                description;

  public SdmAppsTabObj(){}


  public SdmAppsTabObj
  (
    String inOrgId,
    String inAsnId,
    String inAppFullName,
    String inDescription
  )
  {
     this.OrgId = inOrgId;
     this.AsnId = inAsnId;
     this.AppFullName = inAppFullName;
     this.Description = inDescription;
  }
*/

  public String getOrgid()                          { return orgid; }
  public String getAsnid()                          { return asnid; }
  public String getAppfullname()                       { return appfull_name; }
  public String getDescription()                        { return description; }



  public void  setOrgid(String inOrgId )                  { this.orgid = inOrgId; }
  public void  setAsnid(String inAsnId )                  { this.asnid = inAsnId; }
  public void  setAppfullname(String inAppFullName )           { this.appfull_name = inAppFullName; }
  public void  setDescription(String inDescription )             { this.description = inDescription; }

  //Override equals() and hashCode()
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object inObject)
  {
    if (this == inObject) { return true; }
    if (inObject == null) { return false; }
    if (!(inObject instanceof SdmAppsTabObj)) { return false; }
    SdmAppsTabObj other = (SdmAppsTabObj) inObject;
    if( orgid == null )
    if( other.orgid != null ) { return false; }
    else if( !orgid.equals(other.orgid) ) { return false; }
    if( asnid == null )
    if( other.asnid != null ) { return false; }
    else if( !asnid.equals(other.asnid) ) { return false; }
    return true;
  }
  public int hashCode()
  {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((orgid == null) ? 0 : orgid.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((asnid == null) ? 0 : asnid.hashCode());
    return result;
  }
}
```

---

---

**SdmAppsAction.java**

```
import SdmAppsTabObj;
import SdmAppsPkeyObj;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class SdmAppsAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<SdmAppsTabObj>{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  SdmAppsTabObj lSdmAppsTabObj = new SdmAppsTabObj();

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        return SUCCESS;

    }

    public SdmAppsTabObj getModel() {

        return lSdmAppsTabObj;

    }
}
```

---

---

**sdm_apps_add.jsp**

```
.....
<h2>Add Apps</h2>
<s:form  action="sdmAppsAction" >
  <s:textfield name="orgid" label="Org" />
  <s:textfield name="asnid" label="Asn" value=""/>
  <s:textfield name="appfull_name" label="App name" value=""/>
  <s:textfield name="description" label="Desc" value=""/>
  <s:submit />
</s:form>

.....
```

---

---

**sdm_apps_success.jsp**

```
.....
<h2>Apps Details</h2>
Org : <s:property value="orgid" /><br>
Asn : <s:property value="asnid" /><br>
App name : <s:property value="appfull_name" /><br>
Desc : <s:property value="description" /><br>
.....
```

---

Comment: To me OGNL is behaving as expected.  You have not defined a public access specifier for your properties so they will not be directly accessible to the view, so OGNL will try to use a getter... and since one of the correct name does not exist it will fail.

Comment: Architecture point of view member's modifier can't be made public.
Even I tried with public which did not work. FYI I am using struts 2.2.1 and OGNL 3.0.
Believe me I tried all possible ways with underscore making good public setter/getter method names, but not success. Removing underscore from property name and good setter/getter name solve all problem.

Comment: If you have in your action: public underscore_test = "Hello from underscore!"; and in your jsp have <property value="underscore_test"/> you will see "Hello from underscore!" I have tested this with 2.2.1.1 however see no reason it would not work earlier.

Comment: Further RollingBoy's answer should be accepted as it works just fine too.

Answer (score 2):

The getter of your appfull_name is

```
public String getAppfullname();
```

instead of:

```
public String getAppfull_name();
```

Also, the name of setter is not correct.